# How can i nest the start of the object

Tags: javascript

I am making a web page to register participants for a store night and they can attend on different number of night for the different stores. I would like to display the different dates per store and how many seats are left. i got this code that gets me almost all the way.

however i'm annoyed with the last part

```
seatsDict[storeName] = {'date':date,'seatsLeft':seatsLeft};
```

where i cant nest the object. Can anyone explain how i get it?

```
var seatsDict = {};
      var keyCount = {};
      for (var i=0; i < seatsjson.length; i++) {
       let storeName = seatsjson[i].Properties[0].Value;
       let date = seatsjson[i].Properties[1].Value;
       let seatsLeft = seatsjson[i].Properties[2].Value;
       if(storeName in keyCount) {
          keyCount[storeName] += 1; 
         } else {
         keyCount[storeName] = 1;
      }
      var counter = keyCount[storeName];
      if (storeName in seatsDict) {
       seatsDict[storeName][counter] = {'date':date,'seatsLeft':seatsLeft}; 
      } else {
       seatsDict[storeName] = {'date':date,'seatsLeft':seatsLeft}; 
      }
      }
```

Comment: It think you need something like this :`seatsDict[storeName] = {};   seatsDict[storeName][counter] = {'date':date,'seatsLeft':seatsLeft}; ` in your else block

Comment: Aaaaand that worked - thanks @Eldar for the quick fix